# Any performance recommendation on file or image storage on database or folder when using

Tags: jhipster

Is there any performance recommendation/practice on file or image storage on either database or server folder when using jHipster. In traditional apps, it is recommended to store file or images in server folder, but as we know on the web front, it is using angular. Any pitfall or strategy which can be shared here ?

Regards
James

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use disk storage when there are large amount of images needs to be store.

Disk I/O always faster than DB connection and then query the result.